# Django custom migration RunPython cannot access ForeignKey field in another database

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm writing a django migration operation to change some data in the 'default' database. My app has access to a 'services' database, which contains data I cannot change.

The two relevant fields in the default.table are:

```
data_sets_to_remove = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=100, default="")
data_sets_new = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), null=True, blank=True)
```

i.e., i'm migrating data from data_sets_to_remove into a new format and adding to data_sets_new. To do this, I need to access data from the 'services' database in the migration operation.

```
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    DataRelease = apps.get_model('registry', "datarelease")
    Survey = apps.get_model('registry', "survey")
    data_release_queryset = DataRelease.objects.using('services').all().values('id', 'name', 'survey')
```

But for some reason, the foreign key field 'survey' on the DataRelease model is not available in this context.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'survey'
>   into field. Choices are: id, name

Can anyone shed any light on this? I assume the issue is around accessing data from a secondary database within a migration operation, but if i run the same code in the console, it works fine...

The relevant Survey and DataRelease models in the services database:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100, unique=True)


class DataRelease(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='data_releases', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:facepalm:

The answer was staring me in the face. Switched the import of the associated models from:

```
DataRelease = apps.get_model('registry', "datarelease")
Survey = apps.get_model('registry', "survey")
```

to:

```
from services.registry.models import DataRelease, Survey
```

Now I can access the related fields in the migration operation. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: You shouldn't, though. `from ... import Survey` will import your _current_ Survey model, where the `apps.get_model()` approach will create a Survey model that reflects the database schema at that point during the migrations. When your Survey model evolves, this is very likely to break that migration.